# Apache VirtualHost multiple domain multiple SSL

Tags: apache, ssl

Hi I have the following use case, I have an application (let's call it foobar) on a remote server /var/www/foobar and I have the following Apache VirtualHost conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  # This is to redirect http traffic to https
  Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.bundle.crt

  ServerName example.com:443
  DocumentRoot /var/www/foobar
</VirtualHost>
```

And its working all fine. Now suppose I have another domain example2.com and I want it to point to the same foobar application. My current thinking is create another VirtualHost below, something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example2.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example2.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example2.com.bundle.crt

  ServerName example2.com:443
  DocumentRoot /var/www/foobar
</VirtualHost>
```

But I was wondering is this the correct way of doing stuff like this? I need both domains to be "independent" so I didn't make a permanent redirect from example2.com to example.com

Comment: Your configuration using two virtual hosts is the usual for two domains. What is the problem? Do you have errors?

Comment: Just wondering is this is a good practice because as you can see both example1.com and example2.com points to the same application.

Comment: It is a common solution to provide access to same application with different names. Usually also involves some custom configuration of each site

Comment: Oh okay thanks I will stick with this conf then, was just wondering if there's any better way, like for instance something ServerAlias but with the SSL cert valid.

Comment: You could use `ServerAlias` and a wildcard as propose @ycr, but then it is needed to use subdomains eg. `*.domain.com` applied to `example1.domain.com` and `example2.domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below,You can use the server alias for this, Also I don't see anything wrong in having 2 virtual hosts as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias example2.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testlink

</VirtualHost>
```

If you are getting unable to get a certificate error, you can create a certificate with a wildcard CN. e.g : `*.com`this will match both example1.com and example2.com.

Comment: But then when I connect to the site using abc.def.co there is no SSL.

Comment: Why SSL is not available?

Comment: When I connect using abc.def.com SSL if fine, cause the cert is for abc.def.com. When I connect using abc.def.co it says no SSL cert. Note that its of 2 different domains instead of subdomains.

Comment: Oops I have missed a m in com, If you want to configure another domain you should have another VirtualHost block for that

Comment: No offense but your answer seems confusing to me now as ServerName and Alias is the same

Comment: Your solution assumes I need to regenerate my SSL cert using a wildcard, correct? But I don't think its a very good practice of using wildcart cert.

Comment: Yes, If you don't wanna go down that path you should have two VirtualHosts.